# Having problem with sending message to the Client-Side

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I'm using WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer on Java Spring. I need to print a message on the client side that is subscribed to server every time I send request to this API routes:

`@PostMapping("/send-message/{id}")`

`@PostMapping("/send-message")`

**Problem IS:**

When Im triggering **`@SendTo`** method - I get the message, but can't get when using **`@SendToUser`** method. It shows nothing except a message that the client is subscribed to the server.

[image: Client console]

I think Im having troubles with understanding the concept of `@SendToUser` method.

Please show me how to correctly use the method **`@SendToUser`** to send a message to a specific user

Here's my configuration:

```
package kz.kazatomprom.ekap.common.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/users");
    }
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        registry
                .addEndpoint("/my-ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Here's my MessageController class:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageController {

    @MessageMapping("/private-message")
    @SendToUser("/topic/private-messages")
    public ResponseMessageDto getPrivateMessage(@Payload String message, Principal principal) {
        return new ResponseMessageDto(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message));
    }

    @MessageMapping("/message")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public ResponseMessageDto getMessage(String message) throws InterruptedException {
        return new ResponseMessageDto(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message));
    }

}
```

Here's code where i send message to the client:

```
@Service
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketService {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    public void notifyUser(String userId, String message) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userId, "/topic/private-messages", message);
    }

    public void notifyFrontend(final String message) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/messages", message);
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/ws")
public class WebSocketController {

    private final WebSocketService webSocketService;

    @PostMapping("/send-message/{id}")
    public void sendMessage(@PathVariable String id, @RequestParam String message) {
        webSocketService.notifyUser(id, message);
    }

    @PostMapping("/send-message")
    public void sendMessage(@RequestParam String message) {

        log.info("SEND MESSAGE");

        webSocketService.notifyFrontend(message);
    }

}
```

And here's a client code where I'm subscribing to this channels:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Real-Time Chat</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stompjs/lib/stomp.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id="msg"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8082/my-ws');
        var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            
            stompClient.subscribe('/user/topic/private-messages', function (message) {
                alert(message);
            })

            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function (message) {
                alert(message);
            });

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```